# iOS Core Graphics how to get middle row of CGImage as vImage_Buffer?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, swift5, cgimage

I'm trying to process only a slice of (not full) CGImage. I have the code below that starts at 0 and gets the entire image buffer. I need to know how to get the pointer to the middle row, so I can pass it in as a parameter.

**How do I get only a center byte row of CGImage ?**

```
extension CGImage {

func processImage() -> UInt {

    guard let imgProvider: CGDataProvider = self.dataProvider,
    let imgBitmapData: CFData = imgProvider.data else {
        return 0
    }
    
    let topLeftPixelPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: CFDataGetBytePtr(imgBitmapData))
    var imgBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: topLeftPixelPointer,
                                  height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                                  width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                                  rowBytes: bytesPerRow)
    
    let specificAddressWithinBuffer = /*??*/ // I'm not sure how to set this to point to a specific row
    var sliceOfBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: /**/,
                                  height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                                  width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                                  rowBytes: bytesPerRow)

   }
}
```

Comment: Define the "center"? If the number of pixels `vImagePixelCount(height)` is even, which is the center byte row - is it from the top half or from the bottom half?

Comment: I want to get a "slice" of the image, and thought that starting with one row would be easier. Center would be the result of integer division of width by 2.